# Downloading images from multiple URL's and display GIFs in table view cells

Tags: ios, image, gif, nsurl, sdwebimage

For each table view cell, I want to display a GIF. The GIF images are coming from 6 different URLs.

I first get all the URL's for each cell

```
let arrayOfImageStrings = ["image0001", "image0002", "image0003", "image0004", "image0005", "image0006"]

let gifObjectForCell = self.arrayOfGifObjects[indexPath.row]

let imageURLLocation : String = arrayOfImageURLs[indexPath.row]

    if (gifObjectForCell?.urlArray!.count == 0) {
        for (var index = 0; index < arrayOfImageStrings.count; index++) {
            if let imageURL = NSURL(string: "http://\(baseURL)/\(imageURLLocation)/\(arrayOfImageStrings[index]).jpg") {
                if let gifObject = gifObjectForCell {
                    gifObject.urlArray?.append(imageURL)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I then used `SDWebImages setAnimationImagesWithURLs`

```
cell?.gifImageView?.sd_setAnimationImagesWithURLs(gifObjectForCell?.urlArray)
```

but it works for only about 5 cells. After this point, either the images in the imageView disappear entirely or the images are mixed with other images from other cells creating an incorrect GIF.

As this doesn't work - what's the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: Please, share the code of cellForRowAtIndexPath. You should be doing something wrong there.